Program not allowed to go into folder
I want to run a tModLoader server on my ubuntu machine. But starting it, i get the following error:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/home/ankeserver/tModLoader/saves' is denied.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, Int64& fileLength, UnixFileMode& filePermissions)
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize, UnixFileMode openPermissions, Int64& fileLength, UnixFileMode& filePermissions, Boolean failForSymlink, Boolean& wasSymlink, Func`4 createOpenException)
   at System.IO.File.OpenHandle(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
   at System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(String path)
   at Terraria.Utilities.FileUtilities.ReadAllBytes(String path, Boolean cloud) in tModLoader\Terraria\Utilities\FileUtilities.cs:line 95
   at Terraria.IO.WorldFile.LoadWorld(Boolean loadFromCloud) in tModLoader\Terraria\IO\WorldFile.cs:line 481

I even ran the program in sudo but it didn't change anything. All the Folders are in the ownership of my user and in my group.
